# RTL or text align right

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

How I do align form to form as right to left in Delhi XE5 for mobile?
I place labels on the form, but can't align the text to the right, same goes for other controls on page.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that in FireMonkey since it has no bidi support. If bidi support is important to you, you should use a different development tool.